# Can I use a Route inside of a Switch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-redux, react-router

I'm working on the routes for my rails/react and redux app, but I can't seem to put a `Route` inside of a `Switch` component like so:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Splash} />
  <AuthRoute path="/login" component={LoginFormContainer} />
  <AuthRoute path="/signup" component={SignupFormContainer} />
  <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={HomeIndexContainer} />
</Switch>
```

When I try to do this, I get an error message saying:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I double checked and I am indeed exporting and importing my `Splash` component the right way; and when I tried changing `Route` to `AuthRoute` or `ProtectedRoute`, it was able to render. Any ideas as to why this is?

Here is what my component looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Splash = () => (
  <div className="splash-page">
    <h1>Music for everyone.</h1>
    <p>Millions of songs. No credit card needed.</p>
    <Link to="/signup">{'Get Spotify Free'.toUpperCase()}</Link>
  </div>
);

export default Splash;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are importing route in-correctly:  What does your import look like?

import {
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

See https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-startfor more info

Comment: Ah! Thank you, that was a silly mistake; just imported it from the wrong library!